# How to send an http_response_code in ajax

Tags: php

I built a login. The login sends the username and password to my ajax. There everything is checked and if it is correct, I get logged in. No I am trying to send a http_response_code(). but with this function http_response_code(401), the code stops. It will not continue, so I wont get logged in or the errors wont be displayed.

Is there any way to do it like I am trying?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit by sending to your ajax what do you mean ?

Comment: What you're doing should work perfectly well, but the devil is in the detail. If you do things in the wrong order, or your client code misinterprets the response, something unexpected will happen. Please post an example that displays the problem. See [mcve]

Comment: Please provide the detail of your AJAX, like what kind of library you use for AJAX or a simple working example that represents your current concern.